# Xarray cannot open url

Tags: python-xarray

I am trying to read netCDF data from the following URL:
http://esg-dn1.nsc.liu.se/thredds/fileServer/esg_dataroot4/cordexdata/cordex/output/SEA-22/SMHI/MOHC-HadGEM2-ES/historical/r1i1p1/SMHI-RCA4/v1/day/pr/v20180528/pr_SEA-22_MOHC-HadGEM2-ES_historical_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_day_19510101-19551230.nc

With xarray, I cannot open the file:

```py
url='http://esg-dn1.nsc.liu.se/thredds/fileServer/esg_dataroot4/cordexdata/cordex/output/SEA-22/SMHI/MOHC-HadGEM2-ES/historical/r1i1p1/SMHI-RCA4/v1/day/pr/v20180528/pr_SEA-22_MOHC-HadGEM2-ES_historical_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_day_19510101-19551230.nc'
 
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset(url)

# xarray cannot open the url
OSError: [Errno -77] NetCDF: Access failure: b'http:...
```

but when I paste the url to browser, it is ready for downloading

any solution?

Comment: Click on that link in private mode or a new session. It’s not a link to a raw netcdf file - you get an html page asking you to log in. You need to figure out how to use an api or some mechanism to provide an authentication token or something to provide direct access to the data, or else download the data and point xarray to the local copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably access using the esgf pyclient: https://esgf-pyclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. As Michael Delgado says in the comments you need a mechanism to authenticate yourself. The esgf client should let you do this for this data.

First, you will need to register for data access. You can do this when you open the url you have given. This will give you a username and password. Once you've done that, install the python client. Then run the following in python before trying to open the url in xarray.

```
from pyesgf.logon import LogonManager
lm = LogonManager()
lm.is_logged_on()
lm.logon(hostname='esgf-node.llnl.gov', interactive=True, bootstrap=True)
lm.is_logged_on()
```

Note: you appear to have a url for accessing the full netCDF, whereas you probably want to open it using opendap. This will mean you do not need to download the full file, but only want you want. Typically, you can modify the url as follows to do that:

```
url = url.replace("fileServer","dodsC")
```